# file read and return a byte array

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, download

i want to read a  mp3 file using java and want to download it in jsp,i want to return byte array or i can only return one byte at a time?.please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Just create a [servlet class](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) which reads the file into an [`InputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) using [`FileInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and write it to the [`OutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) of the [`HttpServletResponse`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29) the [usual Java IO way](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/). Don't forget to set the HTTP [`Content-Length`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) and [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) headers accordingly, else it will be sent with [chunked encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) (which is a tad slower), or the browser won't know what to do with the information. Finally map this servlet on an `url-pattern` in `web.xml` and invoke it by URL wherein you pass the file identifier as request parameter or pathinfo. You can find [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html) a *basic* example of such a servlet.

Comment: thanks balusc,i want to no how can i download a large file i n a handset?(mobile).i m getting error on browser i m able to download a file but on mobile i m getting i m getting exception

Comment: Sorry, I can't parse your English. You need to be more clear and descriptive. Please, there are zillion kinds of errors, which one did you got?

Comment: i m working on a wap project ,i want to download mp3 files when user presses   an option using gprs.i m testing this application using opera browser which is used for(wap-wireless access protocol) ,there i m able to download a file using code u mentioned above.but now i m facing a major problem i m not able to download on mobile 
.may be slow network or speed.what can be the best soloution to make it work.please suggest. byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]intbyteRead = 0;while((byteReadfis.read(buffer)) !os.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);}
i m using this code small sample.

Comment: Yes Ok, but which exception did you got? Exceptions tell something about the cause of the problem. You know, once the cause is *understood*, the solution is *obvious*.

Comment: can i use nio  with jsp for solving this problem?.mobile gives exception like-no request and my code stucks inside while.

Comment: Sounds like the HTTP `Content-Length` is missing. Show the HTTP resposne headers.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply describing serving a file across the web. It sounds like you are already using a servlet container like Tomcat. Why not just let Tomcat serve the file? No code needed and it will probably be done better and more efficiently than a custom solution.